# Reading many small files from S3 very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce

Loading many small files (>200000, 4kbyte) from a S3 Bucket into HDFS via Hive or Pig on AWS EMR is extremely slow. It seems that only one mapper is used to get the data, though I cannot  exactly figure out where the bottleneck is.

**Pig Code Sample**

```
data = load 's3://data-bucket/'  USING PigStorage(',') AS (line:chararray)
```

**Hive Code Sample**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE data (value STRING) LOCATION  's3://data-bucket/';
```

Are there any known settings that speed up the process or increase the number of mappers used to fetch the data?

I tried the following without any noticeable effects:

- Increase #Task Nodes
- set hive.optimize.s3.query=true
- manually set #mappers
- Increase instance type from medium up to xlarge

I know that s3distcp would speed up the process, but I could only get better performance by doing a lot of tweaking including setting #workerThreads and would prefer changing parameters directly in my PIG/Hive scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either :

1. use distcp to merge the file before your job starts : http://snowplowanalytics.com/blog/2013/05/30/dealing-with-hadoops-small-files-problem/
2. have a pig script that will do it for you, once.

If you want to do it through PIG, you need to know how many mappers are spawned. You can play with the following parameters :

```
//  to set mapper = nb block size. Set to true for one per file.
SET pig.noSplitCombination false;
// set size to have SUM(size) / X = wanted number of mappers
SET pig.maxCombinedSplitSize 250000000;
```

Please provide metrics for thoses cases

Comment: thanks for your answer but your two options are already mentioned in my question.1) I know s3distcp is an option, though I could only get these "promised" performance gains by doing a lot of parameter tweaking, it seemed it is not very optimized, but still good. 2) Thats exactly what I want but it seems pig runs only one map job to fetch the data and is incredibly slow...